# Need to show profile wise different home page for SF1 app

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, home-page-component, admin, lightning-home-page

I want to display different home pages for different user based on their profile, we are able to do this for desktop from Setup -> feature setting -> Home -> page assignment, but there is no option for SF1

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, below are the steps :
1)  create home pages and also create tabs for them
2)  go to salesforce navigation from setup - quick search.
3)  Remove default home tab and add all the newly created tabs at top in any order.
4)  from each profile give access to specific tab for respective profile and hide rest of the tabs.